# Need help on Spring MVC hello world

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to learn Spring MVC on NetBeans 8.0.2 using Hibernate and frankly I am stuck. Any help is appreciated. I am only trying to do a very simple "hello world" type site.

Someone would on the first page hit a submit button and the resulting page would have a list of values from the DB. Sounds pretty simple right? 
I've included 5 very short files here that will hopefully help you to help me if you are so inclined. 
"web.xml", "dispatcher-servlet.xml","index.jsp", "TeamController.java", "secondView.jsp"

The way I understand how Spring MVC should work, using my files, is as follows...

1) Running the project from NetBeans, the index.jsp file is brought up. 
This happens because the Web.xml is consulted, which has the following line...

```
"<welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>"
```

once the redirect.jsp is consulted, we see that it has the following...

```
"<% response.sendRedirect("index.htm"); %>"
```

so with that redirect we go back to the web.xml which has the following...

```
"<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>" 
"<url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>"
```

so with that request coming in as index.htm it is to be handled by the dispatcher servlet. 
In the dispatcher servlet's config file, the view resolver will add the following... 
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" 
    p:suffix=".jsp" /> 
so index.htm gets changed to /WEN-INF/jsp/index.jsp and that page is brought up.

2) At this point the index.jsp is brought up. The only thing in this file is a form with a submit button. The intent is just to have someone press the button and info from the DB is returned on screen. I have Hibernate as part of this web project and I have created a java class "Team.java" based on a DB table "Team". It is populated with a few records. 
Currently what I am seeing is that once the index.jsp comes up and I hit submit, it is giving a 404.

This is the URL shown for the form 
     "host:port/HelloWebFour/index.htm "
if I do a view source it shows it as the index.jsp. When I hit submit it gives a 404 with this url 
    "host:port/HelloWebFour/team? "
btw, "HelloWebFour" is the name of my project in NetBeans. 
I am not sure what is happening, if my understanding is right or if I need to add anything. any help is appreciated... 
The very short code files are below...

"Web.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"> 
<context-param> 
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
<param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value> 
</context-param> 
<listener> 
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
</listener> 
<servlet> 
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> 
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> 
<load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup> 
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> 
<url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping> 
<session-config> 
<session-timeout> 
30 
</session-timeout> 
</session-config> 
<welcome-file-list> 
<welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file> 
</welcome-file-list> 

</web-app>
```

---

"dispatcher-servlet.xml"

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> --> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd"     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"> 


<context:component-scan base-package="testnew1" /> 

<bean     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/> 

<!-- 
Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but 
for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must 
define an explicit mapping for it. 
--> 
<bean id="urlMapping" 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping"> 
<property name="mappings"> 
<props> 
<prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop> 
</props> 
</property> 
</bean> 

<bean id="viewResolver" 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" 
p:suffix=".jsp" /> 

<!-- 
The index controller. 
--> 
<bean name="indexController" 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController" 
p:viewName="index" /> 

</beans>
```

---

"index.jsp"

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%> 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 

<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
<title>index.jsp - the submit page</title> 
</head> 

<body> 

<h2>Hit submit to get DB information</h2> 
<form:form method="GET" action="/HelloWebFour/team"> 
<table> 
<tr> 
<td> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
</td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
</form:form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

---

"TeamController.java"

```
package testnew1; 

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller; 
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod; 
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView; 


@Controller 
public class TeamController { 

@RequestMapping(value = "/team", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String getTeam(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb") Team team, 
ModelMap model) { 
model.addAttribute("city", team.getCity()); 
model.addAttribute("state", team.getState()); 
model.addAttribute("nickname", team.getNickname()); 
return "secondView"; 
} 


}
```

---

"secondView.jsp"

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%> 
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
<title>secondView.jsp - the results page</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h2>Database Information</h2> 
<table> 
<tr> 
<td>City</td> 
<td>${city}</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td>State</td> 
<td>${state}</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td>Nickname</td> 
<td>${nickname}</td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
</body> 


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far I see you Submiting to `"/HelloWebFour/team` but your only request handler method is mapped to `/team`, try to submit to just `/team`. I don't use any prefix on Dispatcher mapping so can be a missed `.htm` on url combining with the unknown request url `/HelloWebFour/team`.

Then if one of above solutions work, your method may fail because you are expecting a modelAttribute named as "SpringWeb" of type Team, but your form actually dont post any data and it's modelAttribute is mapped to "command", the default value, so removing this can possibly remove a further error if occurs.